# cordova-firebase-plugin - Use of undeclared identifier 'UNAuthorizationOptions' in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

I am trying to generate a cordova app in iOS 10. I am using `Xcode v7.2.1 (7C1002)`. In my project I have [cordova-firebase-plugin](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase) as a dependency which is generating the following errors when I try to build the app:

```
.../FirebasePlugin.m:113:2: Use of undeclared identifier 'UNAuthorizationOptions'
.../FirebasePlugin.m:114:4: Unknown receiver 'UNUserNotificationCenter'; did you mean 'NSNotificationCenter'?
.../FirebasePlugin.m:114:29: No known class method for selector 'currentNotificationCenter'
.../FirebasePlugin.m:115:3: No known instance method for selector 'requestAuthorizationWithOptions:completionHandler:'
.../FirebasePlugin.m:115:35: Use of undeclared identifier 'authOptions'
```

Block of code that has problems:

**FirebasePlugin.m**

```
// IOS 10
UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptionAlert|UNAuthorizationOptionSound|UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
[[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]
    requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions
                  completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        if ( ![NSThread isMainThread] ) {
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setDelegate:self];
                [[FIRMessaging messaging] setRemoteMessageDelegate:self];
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

                CDVPluginResult *pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus: granted ? CDVCommandStatus_OK : CDVCommandStatus_ERROR];
                [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
            });
        }
        else {
            [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setDelegate:self];
            [[FIRMessaging messaging] setRemoteMessageDelegate:self];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
            CDVPluginResult *pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];
            [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
        }
  }
];
```

I have read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39997331/9436122), but I still can't get rid of the problem. It seems that the code is a bit different. Is there a way to fix that?